# How to obtain a diagonal matrix D such that AD produces columns vectors of length 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 &  -3 & 6\\ 
6 & 6 & 2\\ 
-12 &  2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and I have the following problem statement:

I have tried calculating the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors but I have not been able to obtain the diagonal matrix D such that AD has column vectors of length 1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Exercise statement]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$ be the columns of $A$ and let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $\frac{1}{||a_1||}$, $\frac{1}{||a_2||}$ and $\frac{1}{||a_3||}$ then

$$AD = (\frac{a_1}{||a_1||}|\frac{a_2}{||a_2||}|\frac{a_3}{||a_3||})$$

i.e. the columns of $AD$ are normalized.